# Codeigniter connection to Filezilla Server is getting rejected

Tags: codeigniter, ftp

Here's my controller class

```
public function download_ftp(){
    $this->load->library('ftp');

    $config['hostname'] = 'localhost';
    $config['username'] = 'Admin';
    $config['password'] = 'admin';
    $config['debug']        = TRUE;

    $this->ftp->connect($config);   
}
```

And this is the server log for the operation.

```
(000126)03/12/2017 23:01:53 - (not logged in) (::1)> Connected on port 21, sending welcome message...
(000126)03/12/2017 23:01:53 - (not logged in) (::1)> 220 Welcom
(000126)03/12/2017 23:01:53 - (not logged in) (::1)> USER Admin
(000126)03/12/2017 23:01:53 - (not logged in) (::1)> 331 Password required for admin
(000126)03/12/2017 23:01:53 - (not logged in) (::1)> PASS *****
(000126)03/12/2017 23:01:53 - admin (::1)> 230 Logged on
(000126)03/12/2017 23:01:53 - admin (::1)> EPSV
(000126)03/12/2017 23:01:53 - admin (::1)> 229 Entering Extended Passive Mode (|||983|)
(000126)03/12/2017 23:01:53 - admin (::1)> could not send reply, disconnected.
```

The filezilla server is hosted on localhost. As you can see the function successfully logs in, but the server seems unable to respond and it terminates the connection.

Answer (score 0):

By default, Filezilla accepts passive mode for connection. But at times, the environment dose not support clearly for passive modes. What we normally do in such scenario from ftp client - we switch the mode of connection from Passive to Active.

The Passive property controls whether data connections for uploads/downloads are established in Active or Passive mode. To use Active mode, set the Passive property = false

```
// turn passive mode on
ftp_pasv($conn_id, true);

// turn active mode on
ftp_pasv($conn_id, false);
```